# Is Z3 a sub-field of R?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, real-numbers

The inverse numbers for the items in $\mathbb{Z3}$ are different than in  $\mathbb{R}$ so I assume it's not a sub-field of  $\mathbb{R}$. Am I correct?

And in general, can sub-field of a infinite field be finite?

Comment: It's not even a subset. And yes: there are infinite fieds with finite subfields, but they must have positive characteristic.

Comment: Why not a subset? {0, 1, 2}⊂R isn't it? What am I missing?
And how can a field with positive characteristic be infinite? I though that only with characteristic=0 is infinite.

Comment: Kobi, it's not the "same" 0,1,2. In real numbers, 1+2=3, while in Z3, 1+2=0.  They behave differently, so they're not the same thing.

Comment: Because those numbers $\;0,1,2\;$ are not real numbers but something else: either you can think of them as representatives of equivalence classes in the integers, or what ammounts to the same as possible residue when dividing integers by three.

Comment: Oh gotcha. the "0", "1", "2" are just symbols that can be replaced with, for example, "a", "b", "c". thanks :)

Comment: @KobiT You can have $\{0,1,2\}\subset \mathbb R$, but in that case, you need to redefine what the symbols $+$ and $\cdot$ mean, because in $\mathbb R$, the equation $1+2=0$ is far from correct.

Comment: @Joanpemo is reversed: Note, if $\mathbb F_2$ is the field with two elements, then it is contained in the infinite field $\mathbb F_2(X)$ also of characteristic $2$.  In order for a subfield of a field to be finite, it must have characteristic zero.

Comment: @GEdgar "In order for a subfield of a field to be finite, it must have characteristic zero" ?? I strongly beg to difer: **any** finite field is a counterexample to that claim.

Comment: @Joanpemo ... OK, maybe my wording was a bit off.  What I meant: in order for a subfield of $\mathbb R$ to be finite, it must have characteristic zero (because $\mathbb R$ has characteristic zero).  Therefore $Z3$ is not a sub-field of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any subfield of $\mathbb R$ is automatically of characteristic $0$ and thus contains $\mathbb Q$, in particular it is an infinite field.

Nevertheless, it is possible that a finite field is a subfield of an infinitie field, for example we have $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z(X)$, where the latter is the function field over $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not, because $\mathbb Z_3$ is not really a subset of $\mathbb R$, since $\mathbb Z_3=\mathbb Z/(3\mathbb Z)$

Of course, you can say that $\mathbb Z_3$ can be defined as the set $\{0,1,2\}$, but in that case, the operation $+$ defined on the set **is not the same** as the operation we typically denote as $+$, since $2+2=1$ in $\mathbb Z_3$, but $2+2=4$ in $\mathbb R$.